# Ruby on Railsの Syntax Errorが分からない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsでコントローラーを作成しているのですがその際にでたsyntax errorが解決せず困っています。

エラー内容

```
/Users/hiratashinichi/app3/app/controllers/customer/checkouts_controller.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected ','
line_items:,
```

エラー内容的に :の後のカンマ?の文字種類が違うのかと思うのですがよく分かりません。

試したこととしてはVSCodeの文字の置換でカンマを変えてみたりしましたがよく分からないです。
どなたかご教授頂けると助かります。

情報少なくて申し訳ありません。
以下エラー発生のコントローラー全文です。

```
class Customer::CheckoutsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_customer!
  
    def create
      line_items = current_customer.line_items_checkout
      session = create_session(line_items)
      # Allow redirection to the host that is different to the current host
      redirect_to session.url, allow_other_host: true
    end
  
    private
  
    def create_session(line_items)
      Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
        client_reference_id: current_customer.id,
        customer_email: current_customer.email,
        mode: 'payment',
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items:,
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ['JP']
        },
        shipping_options: [
          {
            shipping_rate_data: {
              type: 'fixed_amount',
              fixed_amount: {
                amount: 500,
                currency: 'jpy'
              },
              display_name: 'Single rate',
            }
          }
        ],
        success_url: root_url,
        cancel_url: "#{root_url}cart_items"
      )
    end
  end
```

Comment: どの行でエラーが出ているのか書いてください。(エラーメッセージを見ると 19 行目のようですが、ソースに行番号が振ってないのでわかりません)

Answer (score 2):

使用されている Ruby のバージョンは何でしょうか。

ハッシュおよびキーワード引数のショートハンド構文は Ruby 3.1 で導入されたものなので、Ruby 3.0 以前のバージョンでは構文エラーとなります。

Comment: Gemfileにて2.6.0になっておりました! これはバージョンを切り替えれば大丈夫なのでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。ハッシュのショートハンド構文を利用したい場合は少なくとも Ruby 3.1 以降にする必要があります。
ただ Ruby を 3.0 以上に上げる場合は Rails も 6.x に上げる必要があります。 
※Ruby 2.6 も Rails 5.2 もサポートが切れているのでショートハンド構文のサポート有無に関わらずバージョンは更新した方が良いでしょう。

念の為ですが、 Ruby 2.6 のままでもショートハンド構文を用いず `line_items: line_items,` と書くことで syntax error は解消するはずです。